# compute $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(DY)^i$ from $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}Y^i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an $m \times m$ matrix $Y$ , and an $m \times m$ diagonal matrix $D$. Now suppose that result of the matrix $X=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}Y^i$ is given, and I want to compute the matrix $X'=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(DY)^i$. Can I express $X'$ in terms of $X$ so that I could use the result of $X$ to compute $X'$?

Answer (score 2):

If both sums converge, you have $1-Y=X^{-1}$ and $(1-DY)^{-1}=X'$. Therefore 
$$
X'=(1-D(1-X^{-1}))^{-1}
$$